# Android Studio - Problem with two Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

The main problem with my Android Studio is: when I opened android studio and somehow it opens two windows (both windows are the same project but one is empty and the other with almost everything but the tools bar is missing and also it freezes the menu when I'm trying to navigate the main menu of android studio).
So, it happens randomly when I open Android Studio.
I just uninstall android studio like 3 times, and I still got the same problem over and over.

Anyone, can help me out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpsR.png)

Comment: Try Shift + F12 (Restore Default Layout) or go to Window Menu -> Restore Default Layout or Ctrl+Shift+F12 to close all active windows

Comment: I did it with those suggestions but it won't do it because when I open Android Studio and get those two windows opens, when that happen those windows are freezes.

Comment: you have tried to uninstall and reinstall the android studio, but have you tried to also fully clear the studio file/folder in your computer ? try CCleaner https://www.ccleaner.com/

Comment: the two first uninstall times that I did, I did just uninstall from control panel and uninstall android studio but the last uninstall that I did: it was uninstalling android studio and erasing some folders (like .android, .androidstudio4.0, and other folders)

Comment: but it didn't work at all